# Spring not accepting list of multipart files: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile

Tags: java, spring

I was sending this via AJAX:

```
var formData = new FormData();
var totalfiles = document.getElementById('files').files.length;
for (var index = 0; index < totalfiles; index++) {
    formData.append("files", document.getElementById('files').files[index]);
}
```

And with my Spring 4 application, it should have been received by this method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mapUploads/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected void check(HttpServletRequest request, List<MultipartFile> files)
```

But for some reason, Spring 4 was telling me that the bean could not be instantiated:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile
```

In debugging mode, it wasn't even entering the method parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the method signature to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mapUploads/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected void check(HttpServletRequest request) {
   MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
   List<MultipartFile> files = multipartRequest.getFiles("files");
}
```

This problem [was solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34721803/9631005). But in that question, OP was only using a single File in his parameter - and this is actually solvable by just adding `MultipartFile` in the parameter signature:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mapUploads/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected void check(HttpServletRequest request, MultipartFile>files)
```

This was my previous circumstance, but I ran into the bean problem when I decided to accept a list of files. I decided to create this question for those who are searching for solutions with related to a *list* of files